# Firebase documentation for flutter does not work for deleting user

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

The following documentation on deleting a user does not work:

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.delete();
} catch on FirebaseAuthException (e) {
  if (e.code == 'requires-recent-login') {
    print('The user must reauthenticate before this operation can be executed.');
  }
}
```

"delete()" is not a function recognized by Flutter. "FirebaseAuthException" is also not recognized by Flutter.

How do I delete a user? Where do I find this information?

Answer (score 0):

Using flutter, if you want to delete firebase accounts together with the associated firestore user collection document, the following method works fine. (documents in user collection named by the firebase uid).

Database Class

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future deleteuser() {
    return userCollection.document(uid).delete();
  }
}
```

Use Firebase version 0.15.0 or above otherwise, Firebase reauthenticateWithCredential() method throw an error like { noSuchMethod: was called on null }.

Authentication Class

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future deleteUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      AuthCredential credentials =
          EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: email, password: password);
      print(user);
      AuthResult result = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials);
      await DatabaseService(uid: result.user.uid)
          .deleteuser(); // called from database class
      await result.user.delete();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the following code inside the clickable event of a flutter widget tree to achieve the goal:

```
onTap: () async {  
     await AuthService().deleteUser(email, password);
}
```